# Alternative for Prompt in React Router V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

What is the alternative for `Prompt` in React Router V6, has it been deprecated, and also hooks like `usePrompt`, `useBlocker` are also not available.

```
<Prompt message="Are you sure you want to leave?" />
```

Comment: React-router-dom v6 no longer exports a Prompt component (or any sort of navigation blocking). I think they may introduce it later, but in the meantime you'll need to revert back to v5 if you want/need to continue using the Prompt component. See this [discussion](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139) on github.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this util (checked on react-router-dom v6.9):

```
import { unstable_useBlocker as useBlocker } from 'react-router-dom'

function Prompt({ when, message }) {
    useBlocker(() => {
        if (when) {
            return ! window.confirm(message)
        }
        return false
    }, [when])

  return <div key={when} />
}

export default Prompt
```

Usage:

```
<Prompt when={condition} message='Are you sure you want to leave?'/>
```

** **Edit, Feb 2024:** **

Use [react-router-prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-prompt), availabe with react-router-dom >= 6.19

Answer (score 1):

Since React Router v6.7.0, the [`unstable_usePrompt`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.19.0/hooks/use-prompt) hook is available. It requires using a data router, e.g. by calling [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.19.0/routers/create-browser-router) (which is recommended for all new React Router web projects).

The documentation provides the following example:

```js
function ImportantForm() {
  let [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

  // Block navigating elsewhere when data has been entered into the input
  unstable_usePrompt({
    message: "Are you sure?",
    when: ({ currentLocation, nextLocation }) =>
      value !== "" &&
      currentLocation.pathname !== nextLocation.pathname,
  });

  return (
    <Form method="post">
      <label>
        Enter some important data:
        <input
          name="data"
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

However, [`useBlocker`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.19.0/hooks/use-blocker) is recommended instead for providing consistency across browsers as it enables handling how the confirmation message is styled. (It also requires a data router.) As of React Router v6.19.0, it no longer has the unstable prefix whereas there are no plans to remove the unstable prefix from `unstable_usePrompt` due to its non-deterministic behavior in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to this problem

It's a hook that prompts the user that they are about to lose the changes, and asks if they want to proceed.

The hook needs two files: `useNavigatingAway.js` and `NavigationBlocker.js` which are based on `useLocation`, `useNavigation`, and `UNSAFE_NavigationContext`; this last one was provided by the people that developed React Router and gives us the alternative to make these kinds of things.

The original article is https://dev.to/bangash1996/detecting-user-leaving-page-with-react-router-dom-v602-33ni, but I changed the names and made it more understandable. I also wrote my version in javascript.

[image: Edit navigating-prompt]

The dialog and menu were developed using MUI, and it's based on React Router Dom 6

Rafael

Comment: I expect you have downvote(s) because your answer comes close to being a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).  A link - even a fancy one - to another place to find code lowers the value of this answer because (a) I have to look somewhere else, (b) that link might die, and (c) without the code IN this answer, my ability to find it via searching here diminishes. It would be better to embed your javascript as a snippet.

Comment: Doesn't work on react-router-dom 6.5: navigator.block is not a function