# Detect route change beforehand in SPA using react-router-dom v6 for routing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am building SPA application. I have component with form changes to which could be either saved or canceled depending which button user pressed. I have a flag which indicates that some changes were made in this form.

I am using `react-router-dom` v6 for routing like this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route />
  <Route />
  <Route />
</Routes>
```

I want to show user a warning when he has **unsaved changes** and trying to navigate to **another page** (another route). It seems to me that there is no such a mechanic, I am also still not able to write a pure js script to solve this problem. `beforeunload` not working for me because it is only triggered on page refresh.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting user leaving page with react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841757/detecting-user-leaving-page-with-react-router)

Comment: React-Router-DOM 6 has been a bit all over the place when it comes to preventing navigation actions, mostly taking the stance of not handling it and removing it as a feature since they consider it to be an anti-pattern. There are various workarounds based on the specific version you are using though. Can you [edit] to specify what specific version of RRD you are using and a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are trying to use? (cont)

Comment: See some of my answers [here](/a/74106847/8690857), [here](/a/74065505/8690857), or [here](/a/77071005/8690857) for various methods. Later RRDv6 versions also export a [useBlocker](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-blocker) hook and an unstable [usePrompt](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-prompt) hook that might be usable. Given the RRD maintainers' stance on blocking navigations, perhaps it would be sufficient to just run some logic when the user does reload or navigate away from the page. In this case something like my answer [here](/a/75550447/8690857) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to find appropriate solution for my case.

Answer (score 0):

This component accompanied by usage of the new [createBrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.21.1/routers/create-browser-router) `react-router-dom` api solved my problem.
Anthough it is still not clear how to appropriately use it with query params, blocker seems not be working when I am changing them.

```
import { useDidUpdate, useDisclosure } from '@mantine/hooks';
import { memo, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { unstable_BlockerFunction, useBlocker } from 'react-router-dom';
import { WarningModal } from '../Modals/WarningModal/WarningModal';

interface Props {
  shouldBlock: boolean | unstable_BlockerFunction;
}

const ChangesUnsavedBlocker = memo((props: Props) => {
  const { shouldBlock } = props;

  const { t } = useTranslation('common', {
    keyPrefix: 'changes_unsaved_blocker',
  });

  // https://reactrouter.com/en/6.21.1/hooks/use-blocker
  const blocker = useBlocker(shouldBlock);

  const [warningShown, { open: showWarning, close: hideWarning }] = useDisclosure(false);

  useDidUpdate(() => {
    if (blocker.state === 'blocked') {
      showWarning();
    } else {
      hideWarning();
    }
  }, [blocker.state]);

  const handleProceed = useCallback(() => {
    blocker.proceed?.();

    hideWarning();
  }, [blocker, hideWarning]);

  const handleReset = useCallback(() => {
    blocker.reset?.();

    hideWarning();
  }, [blocker, hideWarning]);

  return (
    <WarningModal
      width="416px"
      icon="warning"
      maxHeight="348px"
      title={t('title')}
      annotation={t('annotation')}
      approveTitle={t<string>('approve_title')}
      isOpened={warningShown}
      onClose={handleReset}
      onCancel={handleReset}
      onApprove={handleProceed}
    />
  );
});

export { ChangesUnsavedBlocker };
```

Answer (score -1):

Since React-Router v6 doesn't have the `Prompt` component, you can create your own:

```
import { unstable_useBlocker as useBlocker } from 'react-router-dom'

function Prompt(props) {
    const block = props.when
    
    useBlocker(() => {
        if (block) {
            return ! window.confirm(props.message)
        }
        return false
    })

  return (
    <div key={block}/>
  )
}

export default Prompt
```

Now, we can implement this in code:

```
import { Prompt } from 'react-router'

const MyComponent = () => (
  <>
    <Prompt
      when={shouldBlockNavigation}
      message='You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave?'
    />
    {/* Component JSX */}
  </>
)
```

Source for custom Prompt component: [Alternative for Prompt in React Router V6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70178993/alternative-for-prompt-in-react-router-v6/75920683#75920683)

Comment: Check what version of React-Router-DOM the OP is using and check again your suggestion. Also, stomping the global `window.beforeunload` reference is generally considered a rather bad practice, it's better to add/remove event listeners.

Comment: Now your post is little more than a copy/paste of an existing answer with a link to the original post. If this is the case then the correct action should be to vote to close the post as a duplicate, ***not*** provide a duplicate answer.